# Micronaut Cannot Build Native Image Graalvm

Tags: micronaut, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm trying out the Micronaut Application as a Graalvm native image found
[here.](https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/mn-application-aws-lambda-graalvm-gradle-java.html)

But when I'm running the `./gradlew buildNativeLambda` I'm having these exception:

```
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 137
com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage$NativeImageError: Image build request failed with exit status 137
        at com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage.showError(NativeImage.java:1772)
        at com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage.build(NativeImage.java:1519)
        at com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage.performBuild(NativeImage.java:1480)
        at com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage.main(NativeImage.java:1467)


> Task :dockerBuildNative FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Google says it's probably an out of memory exception, but I can't find any example how to solve it.
I'm building the sample project from the [link](https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/mn-application-aws-lambda-graalvm-gradle-java.html) without modifying it, but I can't make it work. Am I missing some config for it to work properly?
I'm working on Mac with 16g memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Docker Desktop application (I´m assuming you´re using this) also needs to be configured to be allowed to use enough RAM:

[image]

The provided value is just an example, it might work with much less already.

Comment: "... it might work with much less already" - It will.